# Setting up DNS record in Ionos hosted domain for SquareSpace

Tags: dns, settings, squarespace

There seems to be a conflict between the DNS settings SquareSpace needs in order to set up a connection to the SquareSpace Analytics Search Console and what DNS settings Ionos will allow.
On Square Space the relevant setting are found at Home > Analytics > Connect followed by logging in with a gmail account and then clicking on Allow. At which we get the error message

> Something went wrong
> Sorry, something went wrong there. Please try again

I raised a query with SquareSpace and their response boils down to

> There's one DNS record missing. You'd need to go into your domain's
> DNS settings in your domain provider's end and then add the following
> record:
> Type: CNAME
> Host: www
> Points To:  ext-cust.squarespace.com

Over to IONOS where the domain is registered and into the DNS settings which are currently

```
MX  @   mx00.1and1.co.uk        
MX  @   mx01.1and1.co.uk    
TXT @   "v=spf1 include:_spf.perfora.net include:_spf.kundenserver.de -all" -   
CNAME   _domainconnect  _domainconnect.1and1.com    Standard Record  
CNAME   autodiscover    adsredir.1and1.info Standard Record  
A   ftp 198.185.159.144
```

and attempt to add a new record as per SquareSpace's instructions above, only to get the error message

> A CNAME record can only be set for a subdomain. To alias your main domain please use *Redirect*

But looking at *redirect* I'm worried that, if I set this up, all the email addresses that use the same domain and Ionos' mail servers will fail. I seem to remember trying this exercise about 2 years ago, but managed to kill everyone's email accounts (!) until I removed it again.

Has anyone had this problem and solved it? It seems specific to SquareSpace / Ionos as they both give a standard set of instructions which they expect to work.

Later

After working with Ionos' customer service desk, they managed to add the required Squarespace DNS entry and they now read

```
TYPE    HOST NAME   VALUE   SERVICE ACTIONS
CNAME   autodiscover.www    adsredir.1and1.info Standard Record 
CNAME   www ext-cust.squarespace.com    -   
CNAME   autodiscover    adsredir.1and1.info Standard Record 
CNAME   _domainconnect  _domainconnect.1and1.com    Standard Record 
TXT @   "v=spf1 include:_spf.perfora.net include:_spf.kundenserver.de -all" -   
MX  @   mx01.1and1.co.uk    -   
MX  @   mx00.1and1.co.uk    -   
A   @   198.185.159.144
```

But the problem persists, something is still wrong when I try to attach the Google search console (AKA Squarespace Analytics Search Console -
Squarespace call it two different names in different parts of their site).

Answer (score 0):

Having fixed the DNS entries to satisfy Squarespace, the "allow" error still persisted.
Squarespace customer service then suggested clearing the browser cache or using a different browser. Clearing the Chrome cache didn't work, but switching from Chrome to MS Edge did. Logging into our Squarespace account on Edge finally let the process run to completion.
I presume there must have been some information still cached in Chrome that Squarespace didn't like, I only cleared the temporary files, not the cookies or the history as I wanted to keep these for other sites.
The cause of the problem remains a mystery.